# How can I shutdown the server when I exit the browser tab?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, google-chrome, django-templates

### How can I shutdown the server when I exit the browser tab `django`

### open server django

in django after server and open website in tab

How can I make the server shutdown if all tabs on the site are closed?

Also, can I control the server to be open in the background and not in the terminal?

I have tried handling the beforeunload event

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
   e.returnValue = 'if you exit?'; //required for Chrome
});
```

But this event only works when the page is refreshed and does not work when the tab is closed

Answer (score 0):

You might setup the server to expect a certain ping (ajax request) from an open tab every 5 seconds. When all pings are gone, you know all tabs are closed. This is a bad practice.
Another option, same idea, is to use websocket connection.

Comment: How will this solve the problem?

Comment: It's just a way for the server to assume that a client is gone. As for the server part, you can schedule a job every minute or so to check timestamp of last ping. If it's more than 5 seconds ago, then shut down the server.